# Display information from SQL database to google chart

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, google-visualization

I'm trying to display information from my SQL database to google charts. 
The project is a health dashboard where I need to display steps, kcal, etc.

I got the information from the database but I'm having trouble looping over it (the same information displays multiple times). I assume the problem is somewhere at the "data.addrows"-code.

```
php
include('template.php');
$query = /** @lang text */ <<
SELECT * FROM project_healthinfo WHERE id = {$_SESSION['userId']} ORDER BY date DESC
END;
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$result = $res->fetch_object();
$content = <<<END
                  <!-- Google Chart script starts here -->
                  <!--Load the AJAX API-->



                    // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
                    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

                    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
                    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
                    // draws it.
                    function drawChart() {

                      // Create the data table.


                            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
                            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                         google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
                      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                    function drawChart() {

                      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
                      data.addColumn('number', 'Steps taken');


                      data.addRows([
                        ['$result->date',  $result->steps],
                        ['$result->date',  $result->steps],
                        ['$result->date',  $result->steps]
                      ]);

                      var options = {
                        chart: {
                          title: ''
                        },
                        width: 550,
                        height: 300
                      };

                      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('steps_chart'));

                      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
                    }
                  </script>
                  <!-- Google Chart script ends here -->
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: note: `google.charts.load` only needs to be called once per page load...

Comment: Have you tried breaking the $content into a before and after section and print out the                         ['$result->date',  $result->steps], in a loop? It looks like you're not calling for the next data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to break the $content into two parts.

```
$before_result_date = <<<EOS
...
EOS;

$after_result_data = <<<EOQ
...
EOS;
```

Then the section between there should be a loop similar to this.

```
while($result = $mysqli->fetch_object()){                      
   printf("['%s', %s],\n",$result->date, $result->steps);
}
```

and all together it would be something like this:

```
include('template.php');
$query = /** @lang text */ <<
SELECT * FROM project_healthinfo WHERE id = 
{$_SESSION['userId']} ORDER BY date DESC
END;

$res = $mysqli->query($query);

print $before_result_date;

while($result = $mysqli->fetch_object()){                      
   printf("['%s', %s],\n",$result->date, $result->steps);
}

print $after_result_date;
```

That should do it.